# Setting an alarm in milliseconds in C

Tags: c, signals

I currently have some C code that uses sigaction to associate a handler to the SIGALRM signal. Then I do alarm(TIME_OUT_IN_SECONDS). Problem is, I need milliseconds, not seconds and alarm takes an integer. How can I set the signal to fire off in milliseconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [`setitimer()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/setitimer/)?

Comment: Thanks, the examples I had seen with setitimer() were all associated with signal() and not sigaction so I wasn't sure if they were compatible. As you can tell, I'm a C newbie :)

Comment: Ah so... You shouldn't worry about this, signal() and sigactions() are just interfaces for the same function.

Comment: But sigaction() should be preferred over signal() for portability issues.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not for portability issues, but to avoid some races the use of the signal() function normally creates.

Comment: Please provide examples when writing an answer