# How do I use the functions setitimer and getitimer?

Tags: c, timer

I'm trying to write a program in c that simulates a processor scheduler. Trying to figure out how to simulate timer interrupts i stumbled upon this thread: [Setting an alarm in milliseconds in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601012/setting-an-alarm-in-milliseconds-in-c)

I read through the man page that was linked but am still confused on how this works. Firstly to clarify the which field is to specify which timer type your working with(real, virt, prof)?

Second, you pass in a struct called itimerval. What does this struct hold?

Third, I'm assuming there's other pieces required to get this to work. Obviously a function to handle the signal produced by the timer, but can someone give me the bones for how this thing is supposed to work?

Comment: My local manual page for `getitimer` says "The `getitimer()` and `setitimer()` functions may be removed in a future version.", so I suggest you try to learn some other method of timing, for example [`timer_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) (the linked manual page have a good example). If you persist in using `setitimer` I recommend you read [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) which have structure definitions and better descriptions (than my local page anyway).

Comment: That seems like a lot of code to instantiate a timer. Are there parts that can be excluded to simplify it a bit?

Comment: From TLPI or my Linux man page, the setitimer() and getitimer() are obsolete, please use POSIX timers API timer_gettime() and timer_settime() instead.